# Hiding a Directory Junction in File Explorer on Windows Via Command Line

Tags: windows, symlink, hidden-files, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm creating a python script to automate creating directory junctions in my Documents folder. After a directory junction is created, I want the file (not the target folder) to be hidden in File Explorer so I don't see it when browsing my Documents folder. **Is there a way to hide directory junctions in File Explorer via the command line?**

I tried `attrib +h C:\Users\MyName\Documents\DirectoryJunctionName` but `DirectoryJunctionName` was still visible in file explorer. `attrib` worked with the same syntax for txt files, so this is something specific to directory junctions and how File Explorer displays them.